# JavaFX: Where to place programmed configuration in extended Nodes?

Tags: javafx

I am creating a series of Node implementations extending out-of-box JavaFX controls. The only addition I add to them is the possibility to persist and read back state of the control.

Some of the extended classes:

`ConfigurableTableView` extending the `TableView` and adding the support to save column order, visibility, size and ordering.
`ConfigurableSplitPane` extending the `SplitPane` and adding the support to save the divider positions.

What I do is reading the configuration on creation:

```
@Override
protected void layoutChildren() {
    super.layoutChildren();
    // ... reading the config data
    // ... adjusting the state of the node
    // --- setting up listeners to catch changes and storing it
}
```

It works almost fine. Some glitch is that this method is called when scene is redrawn or the node is resized. So I added a flag to

```
@Override
protected void layoutChildren() {
    super.layoutChildren();
    if (!alreadySet) {
        alreadySet = true;
        // ... reading the config data
        // ... adjusting the state of the node
        // --- setting up listeners to catch changes and storing it
    }
}
```

This is even more close to what I would like and for tables it works fine. But somehow with SplitPane it fails to work. When I debug, I see that the divider position values are set as they should, but after leaving the method, something overrides them with their defaults.

This brings up the thought that the `layoutChildren` is not the best place to put the code in. But I couldn't figure out any other methods to use.

The method I override and extend should be one that is accessed once when the node is displayed, should be called after the form load process is over (should all the subnodes be available).

Can anyone suggest where should I contribute in?

**UPDATE:**
A made some more debugging by adding listeners on `divider.positionProperty` and some trace to the `setDividerPosition` method (after calling the original implementation). Here is the log output:

```
======DP before: 0 : 0.2761904761904762
======CL_        0 : old: 0.2761904761904762 -> new: 0.26785714285714285
======CL_        0 : old: 0.5 -> new: 0.26785714285714285
======DP after:  0 : 0.2761904761904762
======CL_        0 : old: 0.26785714285714285 -> new: 0.4984126984126984
```

Here the CL_ is the ChangeListener on `divider.positionProperty` and DP is the position setter trace. My value to set was the 0.2761904761904762 value. As it seems, I call the setter with the right value, it calls the setter of the SplitPane which raises **two** calls on property: first is an adjustment of the value (notice, that the old value is already the value I set!) then at a second time with an old value of 0.5 (where it comes from?). After leaving the layout and finishing the display of the scene, something sets again the property to 0.5 (almost).

It indicates that the place in `layoutChildren` it is too early to set the value. But I can't find any other point to set it.